# How to pass a string parameter larger 256 characters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, text, odbc

I'm using long ANSI string values, up to around 512 characters. The column is defined as `TEXT`.

For some reason SQL Server only accepts the first 256 characters, and then gives me an error about missing quotes - presumably because the string was cut off before the end.

An example:

```
UPDATE Authentication SET passwordVerifier = '512466f4e1a4b9a411fc729d9e00cf168c
ddbf8a6569d5659cdf256dd8e1d988d4e8ac55f76bc615f39a52ccf2f071cd5478f8dcdc2c87a395
a8dae1ec50a9393f148353628c5a0cec8d4fca3deaa35f874a6e3f8598f7335655e23bb3d292e83b
ce74304ad04365f74f2e91cbd783147e1e17e5a2f2945a12303997e046d6d1  '
WHERE accountID = '36'
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Seems to work fine; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4fc6/1

Comment: Why are you connecting to SQL Server using the old, legacy ODBC ?? Use the native SQL Client and all those kind of issues go away! I'm pretty sure that limit is an **ODBC problem** - SQL Server **definitely** has no limit at 256 characters.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server itself has no problems accepting more than 256 characters as a parameter. I suspect this is due to your data access layer.

What type of connection are you using to SQL Server?